# lubuntu install on supermicro taking hours

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

i am testing a lubuntu install on a supermicro superserver X10, with a RAID 1of 2 identical 1TB SSD, but i hit 2 snags:

1. i get "Error retrieving accessibility bus address" and i solve by running:

> sudo apt-get install at-spi2-core

*i could do this since i started install from within live mode, so i have access to a terminal.*

2. Install becomes extremely slow...as in it spits a line about once every 30min ... please see image.

Any ideas why this is happening, and can i abort it at this level and still have a working install?

[image]

Comment: can you do partitioning before?

Comment: i could have.  But why, did you gather that the error is Partition related? how??

Comment: in the image, does the line showing "Creating ext4 file system for..." change?

Comment: it never did, only the black screen had numerous output that went fast at the begingin, then stopped at that spi2-core problem i mentioned above, then it started crawling with hardly any progress..if you look at that timestap, it too about 45 min to move in the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I really did not have any resolution for this...
so i opted to get an alternate Ubuntu 18.04.3 server iso and i installed server with encryption.
then i apt installed the lubuntu-desktop.... i still need a GUI as a crutch every now and then... that's why i installed it, in case one is wondering.